# EAS Submit failed for IOS "ITC.apps.validation.bundle_not_available"

Tags: ios, expo

I'm using EAS, i have already a version of my app in production (that was uploaded manually) and i'm trying to submit a new version using "eas submit -p ios" and i'm facing this:

"One or more platforms cannot be created for this app due to your provider's contract state. - Creation of apps for the platform(s) iOS is not available due to your provider's contract state.
An attribute value is invalid. - ITC.apps.validation.bundle_not_available
The provided entity is missing a required attribute - You must provide a value for the attribute 'companyName' with this request"

[Terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWTiX.png)

Answer (score 1):

"Contract state" is usually as a result of pending Agreements to be accepted on the App Store COnnect Portal.

Do that and try again.